# Instance has no attribute _pi

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, package, attributeerror

I'm trying to make a Python module like this:

```
class square:
    def _init_(self):
        self._length = 0
        self._perimeter = 0
        self._area = 0
    def setLength(self, length):
        self._length = float(length)
        self._perimeter = 0
        self._area = 0
    def getLength(self):
        return self._length
    def getPerimeter(self):
        if self._perimeter == 0:
            self._perimeter = float(self._length * 4)
        return self._perimeter
    def getArea(self):
        if self._area == 0:
            self._area = float(self._length * self._length)
        return self._area
class rectangle:
    def _init_(self):
        self._length = 0
        self._width = 0
        self._perimeter = 0
        self._area = 0
    def setLength(self, length):
        self._length = float(length)
        self._perimeter = 0
        self._area = 0
    def getLength(self):
        return self._length
    def setWidth(self, width):
        self._width = float(width)
        self._perimeter = 0
        self._area = 0
    def getWidth(self):
        return self._width
    def getPerimeter(self):
        if self._perimeter == 0:
            perim1 = float(self._length * 2)
            perim2 = float(self._width * 2)
            self._perimeter = float(perim1 + perim2)
        return self._perimeter
    def getArea(self):
        if self._area == 0:
            self._area = float(self._length * self._width)
        return self._area
class circle:
    def _init_(self):
        self._radius = 0
        self._diameter = 0
        self._circumference = 0
        self._pi = 3.14159265
    def setRadius(self, radius):
        self._radius = float(radius)
        self._diameter = float(self._radius * 2)
        self._circumference = 0
    def setDiameter(self, diameter):
        self._diameter = float(diameter)
        self._radius = float(self._diameter / 2)
        self._circumference = 0
    def getRadius(self):
        return self._radius
    def getDiameter(self):
        return self._diameter
    def getPi(self):
        return self._pi
    def getCircumference(self):
        if self._circumference == 0:
            self._circumference = float(self._diameter * self._pi)
        return self._circumference
class triangle:
    def _init_(self):
        self._side = []
        self._side[0] = 0
        self._side[1] = 0
        self._side[2] = 0
        self._side[3] = 0
        self._angle = []
        self._angle[0] = 0
        self._angle[1] = 0
        self._angle[2] = 0
        self._angle[3] = 0
        self._perimeter = 0
        self._area = 0
    def setSide(self, side, length):
        self._side[side] = float(length)
    def getSide(self, side):
        return self._side[side]
    def getPerimeter(self):
        if self._perimeter == 0:
            self._perimeter = side[1] + side[2] + side[3]
        return self._perimeter
    def setAngle(self, angle, measure):
        self._angle[angle] = float(measure)
    def getAngle(self, angle):
        if self._angle[angle] == 0:
            if angle == 1:
                angle1 = self._angle[2]
                angle2 = self._angle[3]
            elif angle == 2:
                angle1 = self._angle[1]
                angle2 = self._angle[3]
            elif angle == 3:
                angle1 = self._angle[1]
                angle2 = self._angle[2]
            anglet = angle1 + angle2
            angler = float(180) - anglet
            self._angle[angle] = angler
        return self.angle[angle]
```

It's part of a package named Mathworks. The calling code is this:

```
import mathworks as mw
mycircle = mw.shapes.circle()
mycircle.setDiameter(5)
circum = mycircle.getCircumference()
print circim
```

When I try two run the second module, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 254, in run_nodebug
  File "<module1>", line 21, in <module>
  File "<module1>", line 17, in main
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mathworks\shapes.py", line 70, in getCircumference
    self._circumference = float(self._diameter * self._pi)
AttributeError: circle instance has no attribute '_pi'
```

What's wrong? It works if I replace `self._pi` with 3.14159265, but I need it to work the other way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't name your initializers correctly, it needs *double* underscores on either end:

```
def __init__(self):
```

You need to correct that for *all* your classes.

Because you didn't name them correctly, they are not being run when you create an instance of your classes.

Next problem you'll run into is your `triangle` initializer; you cannot address indexes in an empty list. Create the whole list in one go instead:

```
def __init__(self):
    self._side = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    self._angle = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    self._perimeter = 0
    self._area = 0
```

Comment: Thanks alot!!!! One more problem: Now, in the Triangle class; I decided to do this:                                                       `tri = mw.shapes.triangle();
    tri.setAngle(1, 52);
    tri.setAngle(2, 45);                                           print tri.getAngle(3)` But now I'm getting this:               `File "C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\mw-test.py", line 19, in <module>
    tri.setAngle(1, 52)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mathworks\shapes.py", line 95, in setAngle
    angle2 = self._angle[3]
AttributeError: triangle instance has no attribute '_angle'`

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos: `self.angle` versus `self._angle`; you need to use the correct attribute name. Last line of the method, `return self.angle[angle]` should be `return self._angle[angle]`.

Comment: @MartijnPeters: Oh. Ok. But you're looking at another error. I was going to fix that.

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos: Did you correct the spelling of your `__init__` function definition for the class yet? It is not correct in your case, because it is not being run.

Comment: @MartijnPeters: Yes. The weird part is that it's on the assignment of angle2, not angle1. That means the first statement worked fine.

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos: Are you certain you reloaded your code? Restart IDLE, I suspect that there is a mismatch between the loaded code and the on-disk file.

Comment: @MartijnPeters: I am using PyScripter, but what you said still worked. Now I have yet _another_ problem; in my test module I posted, it is telling me this: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'shapes'`. ?????

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos: In `mathworks/__init__.py`, make sure you import shapes. Or import `mathworks.shapes` first.

Comment: @MartijnPeters: I imported shapes. When I do what you suggested, it still won't work. My init file is at http://pastebin.com/55fgDMJ8

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos: I see a pattern there; it is `__all__` (double underscore). Otherwise that file looks correct. Make sure you don't have a local file named `mathworks.py` or something. See what `import mathworks; print mathworks.__file__` tells you is being imported.

Comment: Thank you!!! A while ago I had been working on another mathworks module that I saved in the same folder. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

You have the constructor written incorrectly. It should be `__init__`, not `_init_`, i.e. double underscores.

Because you wrote it wrong, it's not being called, so those attributes aren't being created when you instantiate your objects.